# Is mentioning a product or website in each post should be considered spam?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, flagging

If an answer or a question from a specific user continuously mentions a specific website or a product (line) as well as functions as a question or an answer, should we consider these series of posts as spam?

The problematic part of this issue is, such posts offer what they claim. They include a part that function as an answer or a question. However, on the other hand, they include and *piggybacked* product mentioning part, which may be considered spam.

If these posts are considered spam, there may be several solutions:

- Each post is separately refined by editing. A lengthy process. Hopefully the author will stop.
- Comments can be leaved.
- One of the posts may be flagged as spam.
- All of the posts may be flagged as spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [there are guidelines for self-promotion](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Generally it's ok, as long as you disclose any affiliation, and don't post *exclusively* promotional content. If someone is going beyond what you feel is acceptable, please do flag their posts for moderator attention!

Comment: Chapter and verse! @MT: the tone of your question seems to have a specific user or specific content in mind. Please flag or suggest-edits; if the content is accidental, these actions are generally sufficient. If the content is malicious, the user will soon be blocked. [se] as a whole is quite resilient in this sense. If you have more questions, feel free to tag one (or more) of the mods in chat!

Comment: @hoc_age fredley Yes, I have had some specific user in mind. Fortunately, everything those were itching are already scratched and I have learned how to behave in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @MTSan I glanced at a vertical of recent changes and made the mods that might have been on your mind. :) It takes a village, so thank you for bringing it up -- nice Meta!